# Find each match comparing two arrays in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

Im trying to find in **Object 2** if **_type** matches with **filterByCallTypeTitulo** in **Object 1** and if so make a new array with each match with the information inside **Object 2**.

I have tried using the **filter()** method and **forEach** but its not working for me (most likely im doing it wrong).

**Example of what I have tried:**

```
callDataList.filter(value => value.type === filters.voiceFilterViewModel.filterByCallTypeTitulo);
```

**Object 1 (filters.voiceFilterViewModel):**

```
VoiceFilterViewModel {_filterByDateTime: "Duración", _filterByAscDesc: "Descendente", _arrayCallType: Array(1), _filterByCallTypeTitulo: "Internacionales"}
arrayCallType: Array(1)
0: VoiceFilterItemViewModel
callTypes: null
titulo: "Internacionales"
_callTypes: null
_titulo: "Internacionales"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
filterByAscDesc: "Descendente"
filterByCallTypeTitulo: "Internacionales"
filterByDateTime: "Duración"
__proto__: Object
```

**Object 2 (callDataList):**

```
0: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 601, _cost: 0, _type: "Móvil Nacional", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
1: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 79, _cost: 0, _type: "Móvil Nacional", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
2: DetailedUsageVoiceModel {_duration: 1314, _cost: 0, _type: "Numeración corta", _usageDate: Moment, _usageType: "VOZ", …}
```

**Detail Object 2:**

```
0: DetailedUsageVoiceModel
calledNumber: (...)
origin: (...)
startDate: (...)
trafficType: (...)
type: "Móvil Nacional"
```

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried??

Comment: @TusharShukla sorry, I have edited with it now

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt seems right but incomplete to me.
You are filtering the array which will return you an array of matched items.

Next you can run an iteration on the filtered items and make a new array based on it.
I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're seeking but here is my attempt.

```
const matchedItems = callDataList.filter(value => value.type === filters.voiceFilterViewModel.filterByCallTypeTitulo);

const newArr = matchedItems.reduce((accumulator, item) => { 
  accumulator.push({
    "key1": filters.voiceFilterViewModel.titulo,
    "key2": filters.voiceFilterViewModel. filterByAscDesc
  }); 

  return acc;
}, []);
```

You can read more about Array.reduce and accumulator at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: accumulator isnt declared and you never use item either ?

Comment: Does it work now? Is this the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Its not what I was looking for. My new array has to be the same as Object 2 just filtered with whatever match if found in titulo with object 1

Comment: Well, then it's just the filter function that you need. The filter function will simply return an array of matched items. If it is not happening, then maybe something else is causing the issue because this is how the filter is written and the way it works.